# Where do I save reference to list of GMSMarkers

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I'm building an **iOS** application in **Swift 3** which uses a list of `GMSMarker` displayed on a map in my `ViewController`. The list of markers is made from an array of my model `Store`

The code in mi ViewController is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - IBOutlets

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    var stores: [Store]!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        stores = Store.listStores()
    }

  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

I need to know the reference for those marker because I want to change their `snippet` info when something happens in the app.

The trouble is I don't know what is the best way to save the reference following the concept of **MVC (Model, View, Controller)**, I'll going to explain the two options I've thought.

1. Create a global `array` in the `ViewController`, then call my function to create a `GMSMarker` for each `store` in the `Store` array and save it in the global `array`.
2. Import `GoogleMaps` in my `Store` class and create a `GMSMarker` property. In the `init()` initializes the `GMSMarker` and assign it to the created property. Doing it I'll always have a referenced to the marker therefore I think that is inefficient because the marker is only used in one `ViewController` but the `Store` object is used in different parts of the app

Which one is the best way ? Is there any other way to do it better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the relevant information about that marker into a custom structure or class that you could store into Store model, then you can create a method in your controller that return a built marker with the stored information. It's fine because you disconnect Google Services from your own models. So, if you should change Google Maps to other maps framework, you have to change the marker builder method only.